# когда нажимаю build в build settings вылезает ошибка

Tags: unity3d, android-sdk, gradle

[image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/753409484189073519/915172519948976148/unknown.png]

раньше была такая ошибка но я забыл как я ее решал, пробовал переустановить андроид студио. в preferens стоит сдк от андроид студио и моя jdk

Answer (score 0):

Полной ошибки не вижу, но вероятно надо попробовать обновить градль/принять лицензионное соглашение. Если в ошибке есть что-то про license или update - то в интернете есть туториалы как это сделать:)
Например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]